# PowerShell add output column and remove header to get just the total

Tags: powershell, msmq

I am trying to get the total requests in queue for MSMQ not each individual one, but the total.

PS C:\Users\mhall> gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue | ft -prop MessagesInQueue

```
MessagesInQueue
--------
0
4
0
0
0
25
0
17
0
6
0
0
```

Comment: Pipe to `Measure-Object -Sum`

Comment: Measure-Object : Input object "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" is not numeric.
At line:1 char:89
+ gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue | ft -prop MessagesInQueue | Measure-Object <<<<  -Sum
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (Microsoft.Power...t.FormatEndData:FormatEndData) [Measure-Object], PSInval
   idOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonNumericInputObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand

Comment: `... | Measure-Object -Sum MessagesInQueue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum` drop the `ft`part

Comment: | Measure-Object -Sum MessagesInQueue | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum

That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue |
    # sum values from MessagesInQueue
    Measure-Object -Sum MessagesInQueue |
    # remove header
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simplified alternative:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_MSMQ_MSMQQueue | Measure-Object -Sum MessagesInQueue).Sum
```